# How to share Kotlin formatting conventions in project for Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, formatting

I'm looking for some support and tips on how properly share the Kotlin formatting conventions in an Android project that is being opened in both Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA by different team members. I'd like to force the usage of Kotlin coding conventions; and I'd like to avoid asking every developer in the team to change their settings in IDE configuration of the `Code style`.

So far I've been following 2 approaches:

1. Commit the `.editorconfig` file to the repository - but this file does not cover all the settings that we would like to share between developers and IDEs.
2. Commit the files that are located under `.idea/codeStyles/` directory in the root folder of the project. This seems to cover the cases that were not handled by 1), but the `Project.xml` files seems to be altered every time when the project is opened in IntelliJ (if the `Project.xml` has been created in Android Studio, and I suspect vice versa as well).

Moreover, I can see some inconsistencies when I try to format the same Kotlin source file in Android Studio and IntelliJ. Could it be that both IDEs contain different sets of rules of Kotlin official coding conventions?

Comment: `but the Project.xml files seems to be altered every time when the project is opened in IntelliJ` what exactly is altered? Have you set the Code Style to be be stored on the **Project** level and committed `.idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml` and `.idea/codeStyles/Project.xml` files?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to share formatting options is via code style xml.
After you set all the options in your IDEa (in `Editor -> Code Style -> Kotlin`), click gear button next to `Scheme` and choose `Export -> IntelliJ IDEA code style XML` like shown on a picture:

[image]

Share this file with your colleagues, and they can import those settings in a similar way by clicking `Import Scheme...`. Since Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEa, it will understand this file.